# Error with Ez Publish

Tags: php, database, ezpublish

i have an error when i want to install eZ-Teamroom

when i finish the eZ Teamroom installation, i simply run this command in my eZ publish root directory

```
php extension/ezxmlinstaller/bin/php/xmlinstaller.php --template=teamroom/installezteamroom --siteaccess=site
```

i have this error

> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings.
>   You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone
>   _set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting
>   this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected '
>   Europe/Paris' for '2.0/DST' instead in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3\www\eZ\lib
>   \ezutils\classes\ezini.php on line 463
>   Error initializing script: database error: .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, have you followed the error message and checked your PHP timezone setting?

If not, try the following: there is a file called "config.php-RECOMMENDED" in the root of your eZ Publish installation. Make a copy of it in the same location and rename it to simply "config.php" (if it doesn't exist already).

Then, open that file and seek out the "TIMEZONES" section (near the top). There's a line at the end of the section that you can uncomment, and set your timezone by it (via the date_default_timezone_set PHP function). So just check your timezone from:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

and set it there.